# Undefined in the server ng-model input inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have input inside ng-repeat and input had a value from the database . I need to post my input in an object to the server but its undefined. However, when you touched or change the input value it works fine. why input triggers only when you touched or change the value?

html

```
<form name="form">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in vals track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-value="val.ID" ng-model="data.val[$index]">
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button></form>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope){
$scope.data = {};

$scope.fetch = function(){
  $http.get("fetch.php").then(function (response) {
      $scope.vals  = response.data;
  });

}$scope.fetch();

$scope.Submit = function(){
  var formdata = $scope.data;
  $http.post("post.php", formdata)
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
  });}});
```

Comment: where is `data.val` populated?

Comment: ng-model="data.val[$index]" shouldnt this be like this? ng-model="val.ID" i mean you are pointing on another model which is not even an array

Comment: @AlekseySolovey sorry forgot to include the fetch from db.

Comment: @PanosK. it works when i touched or change the input value. But when you leave the value generate by db its undefined. Then what is the best way to send input in an object?

Comment: yes you do not initialize the object you are sending on your fetch you have to do something like $scope.data = data (initiating your data model)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form name="form">
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="val in vals track by $index">
        <input type="text" ng-init="data.val[$index] = val.ID" ng-model="data.val[$index]">
    </li>
</ul>
<button type="button" ng-click="Submit()">Submit</button></form>
```

Comment: I remove this ng-init="data.val=[]" on ul then it works perfectly. That was i looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('Controller', function($scope){
$scope.data = {val:{}};

$scope.Submit = function(){
  var formdata = JSON.stringify($scope.data.val);

  $http.post("post.php", {"val":formdata})
    .then(function(response){
      console.log(response.data);
  });
}});
```